# Debugger from VSCode in WSL does not work - interpreter not working (not loading), any solutions?

Tags: config, windows-subsystem-for-linux, interpreter, vscode-debugger

[image: Interpreter Error in WSL with VSCode]

Can anyone tell me how to correct this problem?
When i press F5 or Ctrl+F5 - you can see the errors.
On bottom bar left side - does not appear the interpreter from the top and right side.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solution that i found was to reinstall WSL.
Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).